# Rename multipart file before saving

Tags: java, spring-boot, multipartform-data, renaming

I have this code where I wanted to rename the before saving it to the file system. I tried other questions here in stack overflow but it doesn't apply for me. Hoping you could help me this is my code.

```
@PostMapping("/api/file/upload")
public @ResponseBody String uploadMultipartFile(@RequestParam("uploadfile") MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            fileStorage.store(file);
            return "File uploaded successfully! -> filename = " + file.getOriginalFilename();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Error -> message = " + e.getMessage();
        }    
}
```

This is my store function:

```
@Override
public void store(MultipartFile file){
    try {
        Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), this.rootLocation.resolve(file.getOriginalFilename()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("FAIL2! -> message2 = " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I tried renaming the original file but it doesn't work

Comment: What is `fileStorage` and how is it implemented? Is it something under your control or an externally provided class? Also show how you tried to 'rename the original file'.

Comment: A walk around is saving and then renaming..

Comment: @Jason already edited it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Multipart object contains data about the upload. Altering its data will not do anything useful.

What you can do is to create your own file pointer, with the name you like, then save the content of your multipart upload to that file. With that, you can [transfer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#transferTo-java.io.File-) the file contents to a file, or you can [stream](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#getInputStream--) the file contents to the created file.